# Exact decimal arithmetic in Julia

Tags: floating-point, julia, multiplication

Due to [the nature of floating-point math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), `.4 * .4` = `0.16000000000000003` in Julia. I want to get the mathematically correct answer of `0.16`, in a CPU-efficient way.  I know round() works, but that requires prior knowledge of the number of decimal places the answer occupies, so it isn't a general solution.

Comment: Floating point math has been addressed.  The fact that this specific case was caused by those issues might be the answer that OP was looking for.  The second (how to get correct answer in Julia) part seems legitimate... He is not after all tied to using floating point.

Comment: "What is the least cpu intensive way" – why do you even care about performance when you didn't even have correctness yet?

Comment: A reasonable option in Julia is rational arithmetic: `4//10 * 4//10` -> `4//25`, and the result of `float(4//25)` is indeed the closest floating point number to 0.16.

Comment: Try https://github.com/stevengj/DecFP.jl

Comment: @BarryGackle I agree, and I've edited to salvage the question.  Consider editing it yourself next time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some options:

1. Use the inbuilt `Rational` type. The most accurate and fastest way would be

   16//100 * 16//100

If you're using very big numbers these might overflow, in which case you can use `BigInt`s instead,

```
big(16)//big(100) * big(16)//big(100)
```

(you don't actually need to wrap them all in `big`s, as the rationals will promote automatically).

You can also use `rationalize(0.16)`, but this may not be quite as accurate or efficient, as the literal `0.16` has already been converted to a `Float64` by the time Julia sees it, so you're converting to a binary floating point and then to a `Rational`.

2. [DecFP.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/DecFP.jl) wraps the Intel implementation of [IEEE-754](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/servlet/opac?punumber=4610933) Decimal floating point. This should be reasonably fast (though not as efficient as binary), but has fixed precision, so you will have to round at some point.
3. [Decimals.jl](https://github.com/tinybike/Decimals.jl) is a "big decimal" floating point library: as it uses arbitrary precision arithmetic, it is going to be slower than DecFP.

To say which is the best would require more information about your intended use.

Comment: Note that DecFP.jl is also *faster* than using the built-in BigFloat type (due to using immutables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `decimal.Decimal` with `PyCall`, but efficiency is going to be Python bound

Import the package:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> @pyimport decimal

julia> const Dec = decimal.Decimal
PyObject <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

Meta-define operations (I think all of these kind of definitions should be part of `PyCall`!):

```
julia> py_methods = Dict(
           :+ => :__add__,
           :* => :__mul__,
           :- => :__sub__,
           (:/) => :__truediv__
       )
Dict{Symbol,Symbol} with 4 entries:
  :/ => :__truediv__
  :+ => :__add__
  :* => :__mul__
  :- => :__sub__

julia> for (op, meth) in py_methods
           op = Expr(:quote, op)
           meth = Expr(:quote, meth)
           @eval Base.($op){T<:PyObject}(x::T, y::T) = x[$meth](y)
       end
```

Do some math with them:

```
julia> x = Dec("0.4")
PyObject Decimal('0.4')

julia> x * x
PyObject Decimal('0.16')

julia> x + x
PyObject Decimal('0.8')

julia> x - x
PyObject Decimal('0.0')

julia> x / x
PyObject Decimal('1')

julia> y = x + x * x / x - x
PyObject Decimal('0.4')
```

Get result:

```
julia> y[:to_eng_string]() |> float
0.4
```

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't bring all of Python in just to solve this, when Steven Johnson's DecFP.jl package works very well, doesn't add much overhead to Julia, and is even faster than using BigFloat!