# Workaround for Julia's floating point arithmetic?

Tags: floating-point, julia

Is there a possible workaround to Julia's floating point and rounding arithmetic wherein it outputs even a simple value such as `1.6` to be `1.6000000000000012`

Since I intend to use Julia to prove the degree of exactness of a quadrature method, I need to eventually show that the computed value of an integral equals its exact value, but due to these discrepancies in the trailing decimals in some cases, I am unable to do so.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1

Comment: Did you consider [BigFloat](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/numbers/#Base.BigFloat)?

Comment: @Philip : No, I haven't, but wouldn't the same discrepancy creep up in BigFloat as well, the only difference would be the position of the erroneous decimal right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by discrepancy. If you mean "I typed 1.6 but I got something not exactly 1.6" then check out the link; you'll see that you may prefer to initialize the number manually, i.e. you can get as close to exactly 1.6 as you please. If you mean "as I do floating point arithmetic small errors will accrue"--well, that's exactly why one should use an arbitrary-precision floating point number and think carefully through its use to keep those errors within tolerable bounds :).

Comment: If *any* inexactness at all, even within an arbitrarily tight boundary, is intolerable, then you need [exact arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264742/exact-decimal-arithmetic-in-julia)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary

Comment: @stark, just curious if you've found something different in any other language you've used?  If so, it's likely that the language is just hiding the extra decimal points from you.  (An exception might (or might not) be Mathematica, which I believe makes extensive use of Rational numbers.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Julia you can use `Rational` types to represent rational numbers without losing precision. See the docs [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/#Rational-Numbers-1).
However, you will still need to be very careful with your computations not to promote `Rational` to `Real`.

Your example of `1.6` could be represented as follows:

```
> x = 16//10
8//5
```

Julia would then remember the denominator and numerator and store the value as such. You could use these rational numbers to compare your derived value to the true value.

If at the end you need to convert back to floating point numbers (because for example your result was irrational) than you can use the `BigFloat` type to get higher precision. `Rational` numbers would give you precision improvement even when using `BigFloats`:

```
> @printf "%.100f" BigFloat(1.6 - 1.5)
0.1000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

> @printf "%.100f" BigFloat(16//10 - 15//10)
0.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002159042138773611156347
```

Answer (score 7):

Posting comment as an answer...see [Exact decimal arithmetic in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264742/exact-decimal-arithmetic-in-julia) and likely use one of [BigFloat](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/numbers/#Base.BigFloat) or [Rational](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/#rational-numbers); use the former if you just need your floats to have precision to "at least **N** decimal places" where **N** is up to you; use the latter if an arbitrarily and boundedly small error still breaks what you're doing.

If you use `BigFloat`, you'll probably want to manually initialize your literal values:

> Note that because decimal literals are converted to floating point
>   numbers when parsed, BigFloat(2.1) may not yield what you expect. You
>   may instead prefer to initialize constants from strings via parse(),
>   or using the big string literal.
>
> julia> BigFloat(2.1)
>   2.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625000000000000000000000000000
>
> julia> big"2.1"
>   2.099999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999986

Answer (score 3):

This is an artifact of the fact that floating-point numbers are stored as a fixed, finite number of bits (32 or 64 typically), which cannot represent any arbitrary quantity with infinite precision. In particular, because they use a base 2 representation, a quantity that can be represented exactly in base 10 (such as 1.6) may not be exactly representable in base 2 and vice-versa. You'll have to take this finite precision into account in your proof.

I have no experience with julia specifically, but typically there are more than 1 numeric type available for a programming language. Perhaps there exists an arbitrary-precision floating point library you can use.